# Flag in front of the house in 'Philomena'

Tags: props, philomena

In *[Philomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philomena_(film))*, what flag was flown to the right of the U.S. flag in front of Peter Olsson's house?

[image: Peter Olsson's house]

Answer (score 6):

Seen to the right of the U.S. flag is the **[state flag of Maryland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Maryland)**

[image: Maryland flag]

The real-life location of the house is in Potomac, Maryland.